# Print command output while storing in variable

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection, tee

I am running unit tests in a bash shell, which can take some time to finish, and those tests print output as they run. I want this output to be printed, and I also want the output to be stored in a variable. However, I want these things to be done concurrently if possible, like the `tee` command does when writing to a file. Perhaps `tee` works in this case too…

So I am currently doing this:

```
output=$(ginkgo -r -cover)
echo "$output"
```

However, this obviously won't print the unit test output until all the tests have run. So how can I get the output to print as the tests run while also storing that output in a variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
output=$(ginkgo -r -cover | tee /dev/fd/2)
```

You can use tee to send stdout to both stdout and stderr. stdout is captured into your variable, stderr is printed.

Comment: Thanks. As a follow up, how can I determine whether `ginkgo` failed. `$?` is going to print 0 either way in this situation.

Comment: `$( )` runs its contents in a subshell, so `PIPESTATUS` will not be available from the parent shell. But you can have the subshell propagate the pipe status as *its* exit status with `output=$(ginkgo -r -cover | tee /dev/fd/2; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})`

Answer (score 4):

If your shell is Bash:

```
ginkgo -r -cover | tee ginkgo.out
output="$(< ginkgo.out)" && rm ginkgo.out
```

You may want to consider `|&` instead of `|` if you want to capture the standard error stream too. You may want to dispense with the `rm` if you would like to keep the output file.

If you don't like temporary files and you are running interactively,

```
output="(ginkgo -r -cover |& tee /dev/tty)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought of this, but was hoping for a method that doesn't involve a temporary file.

Comment: @AlexP, how about an approach that uses named pipes? It's more flexible than addressing /dev/tty directly